# Standard SLDs for OpenStreetMaps?

Tags: openstreetmap, sld

We have downloaded OSM data for our region and loaded them into PostGIS using osm2pgsql. So far so good. On top we have GeoServer and we would like to expose the OSM data using WMS. We would as well like to style data like in "standard" OpenStreetMaps (e.g. osm.org) as this cartography is well designed. We have tried to download som standard SLD for OSM data, but there seem to all sorts of problems using these SLDs (XML parsing errors, invalid content, etc.).

Any good ideas how to reuse an OSM SLD to style OSM through WMS?

Answer (score 6):

I have used [this](https://github.com/FlorentDotMe/archives/tree/master/2013.03.23-OSM-Styles-for-GeoServer) one, created (but no longer maintained) by Florent Bervas, and it is quite good. Unfortunately, it only has lines and polygons style, but maybe it will help you.

Comment: I tried the osm_lines.sld but I get a lot of errors when validating the stylesheet in geoserver's SLD editor.  The data was imported to postgis from an osm shapefile extract.  Using Geserver 2.1-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: try to upload without validation. I did not validate the SLD. Just uploaded it, and saved.

Comment: Hi, Yes this was exactly my problem - the validation went wrong. I will try and use without validating

Answer (score 2):

Haven't played with these yet but check out [these styles](http://github.com/mitchelljj/openstreetmap-sld) on github

Comment: These just make my shapefile blank

Answer (score 2):

They may not be exactly right, but I am working with modified versions of the ones included in OSM-in-a-Box (http://dev.ifs.hsr.ch/redmine/projects/osminabox/wiki). A preview is available at that first link.

You can get to the SLDs directly in the source from:

http://dev.ifs.hsr.ch/redmine/projects/osminabox/repository/revisions/master/show/Code/osm2gis/geoserver/geoserver_data/styles

Comment: That link requires a login. If you could please post the styles somewhere accessible, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70641/does-anyone-display-osm-through-mapserver-arcgisserver-or-geoserver No direct link, but accessible with a few steps. Cookies are needed.

Answer (score 1):

The map that you can browse on

http://www.openstreetmap.org/

is quite problably not rendered with geoserver but with a tile server like mapnik instead.

Luckily you can **easily** (no, seriously) set up a server to render tiles like those on the OSM web site using [TileDrawer](http://tiledrawer.com/).
Unfortunately at the moment there is an [issue](https://github.com/migurski/Tile-Drawer/issues/2) that the author is working on that could prevent your setup from working automagically. I suggest you wait until the issue has been fixed. If you can't wait just make sure you install *python-cssutils* before launching the script.

If you find that TileDrawer takes a *lot* (like minutes) to render tiles, consider applying the following indexes to the planet_osm database (shameless plug):

http://unicolet.blogspot.it/2012/06/improving-tiledrawer-rendering-speed.html

Comment: TileDrawer links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

This rather indirect but what about converting the OSM style file to SLD? There's a tool for [converting Mapnik style files to SLD](https://github.com/dwins/mapnik2geotools). You might want to consider that option. Good luck. :)