# SLD for OSM data in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, sld

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Standard SLDs for OpenStreetMaps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17299/standard-slds-for-openstreetmaps)

I can't find a good SLD for OSM.
I downloaded the OSM data and imported it to PostGIS. With GeoServer I use it as a data source to create my layers.

Is there no open source SLD for OSM out there?

Comment: Indeed duplicate