# Is there any instructions to download OSM in postgres database?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openstreetmap, postgresql, sld

Is there any instructions to download OSM in postgres database? I use geosuite (geoserver, postgres, postgis). I'd like to download USA and Russia (1-12 levels). I also want to download sld styles. (Is there any standard way).

So, there is intranet. We use geosuite. And I'd like to download OSM with sld styles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of different methods, depending what you want to do with the data (routing, general GIS, rendering with Mapnik...).

You can find quite a lot on the OSM wiki. osm2postgresql (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2postgresql) is my personal fav but you can have a look at the other ones. They will allow you to import an *.osm file into the database.

To get the osm file itself, also many solutions:

- Click on "Export" on the OSM page (is ok for a one-time download)
- Use one of the APIs to download selectively and / or to automatically update your database with the latest OSM data http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Databases
- Download an already processed osm file from a provider like Geofabrik: http://www.geofabrik.de/en/data/download.html (you can also directly download GIS-ready files, like shp)
- Finally (and slightly off-topic), you can use the HOT-export tool to create custom GIS files (shapefiles, PostGIS dumps...) http://export.hotosm.org/en

And one tutorial on BostonGIS: http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=loading_osm_postgis

I am not aware of any standard sld files for OSM data but maybe someone can prove me wrong?

Comment: I' d like to display this data in Geoserver as WMS layer. Then I want to cache data (I have 20 terrabyte on computer). After all I'd like to display this layer in ArcGis Server.

Comment: For the caching, I would have a kiik at Geowebcache http://geowebcache.org/

Comment: sorry, I would have a _look_

Comment: I use Windows 7. Is there any restrictions?

Comment: Not that I know of. I have been able to make it work on 7

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17299/standard-slds-for-openstreetmaps for SLD for OSM